# PHP can't write to web server, even with chown

Tags: php, apache, file, centos, centos7

So I'm trying to set up [FileRun](http://www.filerun.com/) on my CentOS 7 Apache server, but it's saying that PHP doesn't have any permission to write. I've tried using `chown` and `chmod` (both with `sudo`) but that's not made any difference. I've found the error log that repeats what I've just said, if you need it:

> [08-Feb-2017 19:35:50 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/www/html/system/data/temp/cache.translation.english.tmp.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/system/classes/vendor/FileRun/Utils/Cache.php on line 17

Anything else I can try?

**EDIT:** I was asked to include the output of `ls -ltr`, so here you go. This is what I get.

[image: directory listing]

(Sorry for providing it as an image, but pasting it as text would mean I'd have to format it properly.)

Comment: What parameters did you pass to `chown` and `chmod`?

Comment: @Kisaragi I used `sudo chown apache:apache -R /var/www/html` and `sudo chmod 0775 -R /var/www/html`.

Comment: try `sudo chown -R apache /var/www/html` and `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html`

Comment: @Kisaragi nope, still ain't working. :c

Comment: selinux getting in the way?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the output of `ls -ltr` ?

Comment: @Kisaragi Done. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try :

> chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/

and

> semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t 'data'

then

> setsebool -P httpd_unified 1

restart httpd and php-fpm daemon.

> systemctl restart httpd ; systemctl restart php-fpm

Open your browser at **http://your_ip_server**

Comment: I meant to add years ago - it was actually `www-data` on mine (Ubuntu), but nevertheless, the first one worked. I tend to use that and `chmod` whenever there's a permissions issue now. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing selinux is quietly blocking you.

Try `setenforce permissive` and see if it doesn't magically start working.

Then read this short article.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-selinux-on-centos-7-part-1-basic-concepts

Answer (score 0):

I can't post a comment on here, but try

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
```

Also what does it list if you say

```
ls -l /var/www
```

And

```
ls -l /var/www/html
```

Also the owner of the file, or the group owner of the file, must be/contain the same user who is listed as the owner of your website contents. In this case specifically, the owner of var/www/html/system/classes/vendor/FileRun/Utils/**Cache.php**

Comment: I've tried the `chown` command, but that didn't make any change. As for `ls -l`, directories have drwxrwxr-x and files have -rwxrwxr-x.